# Bounds for the eigenvalues of a matrix in a finite differences scheme

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

While implementing a numerical solution to a PDE with finite differences, the following scheme arises:

$$v_{j+1} = Av_j$$

Where

$$A =\begin{bmatrix}
            1-4\lambda&(2+\mu h)\lambda&&\\
            (2-\mu h)\lambda&1-4\lambda&(2+\mu h)\lambda&\\
            &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
            &(2-\mu h)\lambda&1-4\lambda&(2+\mu h)\lambda\\
            &&(2-\mu h)\lambda&1-4\lambda\\
            \end{bmatrix}_{n\times n}$$

In which $\lambda, \mu$ and $h$ are all positive numbers, and $h$ is really really small. So, we know that for this scheme to be convergent one must prove that all eigenvalues $a$ of $A$ follow $|a|<1$. And so, I try to transform $A$ into something more *treatable*, and I end up with

$$A = I + 2\lambda\begin{bmatrix}
            -2&1+\frac{\mu h}{2}&&\\
            1-\frac{\mu h}{2}&-2&1+\frac{\mu h}{2}&\\
            &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
            &1-\frac{\mu h}{2}&-2&1+\frac{\mu h}{2}\\
            &&1-\frac{\mu h}{2}&-2\\
            \end{bmatrix}$$

This other matrix is quite similar to a well-known matrix:
$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
            -2&1&&\\
            1&-2&1&\\
            &\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
            &1&-2&1\\
            &&1&-2\\
            \end{bmatrix}$$
whose eigenvalues, according to my notes, are $2(1-\cos\theta)$ for $\theta = j\pi/(n+1)$ with $j=1,2,\dots,n$.

Both matrices are quite similar!, is there a way of finding an explicit form of the eigenvalues of $A$ (or at least a way to prove that it will be bounded by 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eigenvalues of a tridiagonal [Toepliz matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix) $A$ given in the question are

$$\mathrm{eig}_{k}(A)=(1-4\lambda)+2\sqrt{(4-\mu^2 h^2)\lambda^2}\cos\left[\frac{k\pi}{(n+1)}\right], \quad k=1\cdots n $$

See [doi:10.1016/S0024-3795(99)00114-7](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0024-3795(99)00114-7)

Comment: Wow man, lot's of thanks.